# Where do I download Iesi.Collections from?

Tags: nhibernate, iesi-collections

Trying out nHibernate, it says it can't find Iesi.Collections.

Where can I get this from? Shouldn't it ship with the nHibernate download if it is so vital?

Comment: Check this site out to browse the IesiCollections code. http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=3190

Answer (score 3):

The source for Iesi.Collections delivered with NHibernate is here:
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/3.3.x/src

During 2012 it was moved to separate repository:
https://github.com/nhibernate/iesi.collections
Recently master in that repo was changed heavily to adjust to .Net 4, but before that the API had been essentially unchanged for many years.

Binaries of new and old versions are available on NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an old question, but it's [available via NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Iesi.Collections).

[image]